# Not all packages are installed in MYSQL (developer mode:default mode)

Tags: mysql

These are the packages that are installing in  developer mode of mysql

[image]

but these are the expected packages(below). MYSQL server ,router, shell are not even showing in above picture.

[image]

Only two requirements are not fulfilled.

[image]

and i don't know what to do now

Comment: the emssages says all install a visuslastio 2015/2017/2019 and python on your computer and they will be installed

Comment: but i have installed without these two once but now when i do window its not working.SHould i must install these two ?

Comment: that you must explain a litle better mysql and workbench and all connectors work fien without those.

Comment: without installing these two how i will get my sql server workbench and shell?

Comment: they rest gets installed even without them, i have poython 64 bit and it doesn't install, but for python you make pip install ymsqlclient and everything runs smoothly. You don't need the visual studio addon from mysql you have the connector that is enough to connect you to the database and do everything.

Comment: i have instlled pip install ymsqlclient  and python 32 bit and now "shell" andmysql router are visible for download but server and workbench is still missing .Can you help me with that? i will be thankful

Comment: then you didn't select it in the installer.